# Lumen throws CORS only with validation

Tags: laravel, cors, lumen

I've enabled CORS in my nginx and it seems to work OK until I add this peace of code to the function store(Request $request):

```
public function store(Request $request){

       $validated = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'file' => 'mimes:application/zip,application/x-rar-compressed,application/x-7z-compressed'
```

As soon as I add $request->validate() I always get CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'aaa.com/upload' from origin 'bbb.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It doesn't matter if the validation passes or not. If I remove this validation, everything works correctly.

How can "validation" mess up NGINX configuration?

EDIT:
Nginx config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: Show us your nginx configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Your response is returning an error, thus the improper response headers, most likely a 403 while a properly validated response should have been a 200 or 202.

If you are using the 3 most recent versions of Laravel/Lumen, you shouldn't worry about manually setting up your CORS configurations. The now built-in Laravel-CORS package takes care of that for you.

Check out this link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#cors

Following that documentation:

```
// $APP_FOLDER/config/cors.php
<?php


return [
    'paths' => ['api/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

That configuration should open it up without restrictions. Just adjust the configurations to fit your needs.

Restart your web server and it should do you fine.

Comment: About what kind of error are you talking about? I'm using newest LUMEN and use validation from the documentation. There are not errors in logs/ directory. So how come there be an incorrect response from the server?

And why should I use extra package if NGINX configuration can work this out?

Comment: That's rude. Anyway, As far as I can see you are still handling CORS manually instead of utilizing the built-in CORS package. Good luck to you.

Comment: Because that does not answer my question. Which was why simple validation messes up CORS. And this is not a laravel but simple lumen project with single endpoint. I want to understand the problem and not blindly use extra package without understanding the issue.